# Could not locate sqlite database with RestKit 0.2

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit 0.2 with CoredData in my project but I am not able find sqlite database file in my project.  Normally (Without Restkit) Sqlite database is located at

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[SDK version]/Applications/[App GUID]/Documents
```

But I cannot find SQLITE database path of my project at this path.

I followed the example of RKGist example and using that I initialized my RKObjectManager. I am using code below to set up my RKObjectManager

```
 NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"momd"]];
  // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
  NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
  RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
  // Initialize the Core Data stack
  [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
  NSError* error = nil;
  NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
  NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);
  [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

  // Set the default store shared instance
  [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

  // Configure the object manager
  RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://69.164.209.214"]];
  objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
  [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
```

I am able to properly map JSON data from the server to my NSManagedObject entities.

I am not sure whether my data is stored in database or not as I cannot find my SQLITE database file of my project.

Thanx,

Regards,

tek3

Comment: Your using addInMemoryPersistentStore, so there isn't an SQLite file to find... Do you want to use addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:... ?

Comment: @Wain - Yeah I found that already. I corrected this and my SQLITE data base is there. Thanks for replying buddy.